# Upload file with unknown size

Tags: java, upload, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

How can I upload a file by Google Drive API  If the length is unknown at the time of the request? I found this way https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#resumable but I can't understand how can I say to the server the stream is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

There is additional information here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/MediaUpload#Resumable_Media_Upload